# Exclude ids from (permanent) filter in List component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, admin-on-rest, react-admin

**This question is related to react-admin and its related components**

How do you exclude ids from the filter prop of a List component? The code below will give me a list of records with ids 1,3 and 5. I want to do the opposite, and exclude them from the list.

If there's no simple way of doing this, how can I get an array of ids of the records in a resource? Thanks in advance!

```
<List {...props}  filter={{ id : [1,3,5] }} >
  <Datagrid>
    <TextField source="id" />
    <TextField source="title" />
    <TextField source="body" />
  </Datagrid>
</List>
```

Comment: What are on the `{...props}`?

Comment: Hi @Tony, I'm trying to build a custom component in react-admin.... whereby from the edit view of a record in a 'collections' resource, I want to add to to it an array of ids of records from another resource called 'activities', via react-admin's List component. 

I've got that functionality working, but what I want to achieve is that the next time I add activities to this collection, the list should filter out activities already in this collection. 

The `{...props}` are passed from the Edit component of the collections record to the List component. It includes the following props.

Comment: basePath
    children
    crudGetOne
    dispatchCrudUpdate
    record
    hasCreate
    hasEdit
    hasShow
    hasList
    id
    isLoading
    location
    match
    resetForm
    resource
    startUndoable
    title
    translate
    undoable
    version

Answer (score 1):

Assume in your state you have the following id's

```
state = {
   allID: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ... n],
};
```

Now assuming you want to show all except where id is `3,5, 7` You can do the following

```
render() {
  const { allID } = this.state;
  const IdToExclude = [3,5,7];
  const filteredID = allID.filter(id => {
     return !IdToExclude.includes(id)
  });
  return (
      <List {...props}  filter={{ id : filteredID }} >
        <Datagrid>
           <TextField source="id" />
           <TextField source="title" />
           <TextField source="body" />
        </Datagrid>
      </List>
  );
}
```

Now I am using Array.includes to exclude from your list of ID's read more on it. [MDN Array Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)